# Tomcat slow loading pages on wireless devices

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have a web app running in tomcat, on local machine and wired connection(one desktop) it runs fine and loads fast. However on wireless devices(phones) and VM(in the said desktop connected in wire) it does load super slow. It just keeps loading with no content then if you stopped loading the page, the content will be showed. What do you think is the problem? The router, server and client is connected to a switch.

Comment: are you using the same ui code? Get the UI out of the way and measure the response time. Try htmlunit or something lower level

Comment: @efekctive Yes same ui code. I tried another router and it works fine on wireless. I think the problem is on the first router. I have tp-link tl-wr940n router

Comment: Ok. That was my suspicion.